# spring mvc - how to remove the word 'resources' when calling js,css,images

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, resources

I have a *resources* folder in my *WebContent* folder that contains css, js, and images... Then i declare *mvc resource mapping* to locate all the resources file... but when i tried to call/acccess the file in my jsp, why is that i need to include the word **resources**?... do you know how can i remove it but still able to access my resources?

**project structure**

```
  WebContent
      |_resources
          |_images
          |_js
      |_WEB-INF
          |_jsp
             |_header.jsp
```

**header.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.min.js" />"></script>
```

**dispatcher.xml**

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />  
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

above code works perfectly, but i want to exclude the word resources in path..
without writing one by one all the inside resources folder (like sample below)

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/resources/images/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/resources/css/" />
```

what i need is something like this... but still declaring one line mvc resource mapping

```
<script src="<c:url value="/js/jquery.min.js" />"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/css/owl.carousel.min.css" />">
<img src="<c:url value="/images/pix/world.jpg" />" alt="user">
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the server is tomcat? If you use the server is tomcat, you can do the      following configuration
  `<Url-pattern> / </ url-pattern>` means to intercept all requests.
If you need to deal with static resources js, css, etc., you can add in web.xml written before dispatcherServlet

```
  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Default is Tomcat's default servlet！